# Elasticsearch not sure if i need to use a bool query

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using ES for my Laravel app, and I am not sure if I need to use a bool query.

In my query I need to do:

A fulltext search on "title" field

A filter that checks that "price" field is between 1 - 9999

A filter that checks that "status" field is equal to 1.

So do I need to do a bool query for the stuff above? Setting title and status as (must) and price as (should)

Or can I simply do something like:

```
 'filtered' => [
    'filter' => [
      ['term' => [ 'status' =>  1] ],
                            [ 'range' => [
                                    'price' => [
                                        'gte' => 1,
                                        'lte' => 99999,
                                    ]
                                ]
    ],
    'query' => [
      'match' => Input::get('query', ''),
      ],
    ],
  ],
```

Or Updated:

```
'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
                ],
                'filter'=> [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['term' => [ 'active' =>  1] ],
                            [ 'range' => [
                                    'price' => [
                                        'gte' => 1,
                                        'lte' => 99999,
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setups is (theoretically) correct, but the syntax is a bit off.  First the theory:

Queries are used to determine scoring and relevance.  Queries basically determine the rank of documents and the order that they are returned in.

Filters are simple inclusion/exclusion criteria.  If a document matches the filter, is is included in the results.  If it doesn't match...it isn't included.  Since filters don't perform any scoring, they are considerably faster (and can be cached easily).

So, use filters for simple inclusion/exclusion criteria. And use queries for anything that needs to affect score (like full-text searches).

Which means your query is exactly correct.  But the syntax needs a bit of tweaking:

```
'filtered' => [
    'filter' => [
      'bool' => [
         'must' => [
            ['term' => [ 'status' =>  1] ], 
            [ 
               'range' => [
                  'price' => [
                      'gte' => 1,
                      'lte' => 99999,
                  ]
               ] 
            ]
         ]               
      ]
  ],
  'query' => [
      'match' => [
        'title' => Input::get('query', '')
      ]
   ]
]
```

Basically, the `filter` clause of a `filtered` query accepts a single filter.  Since you need to define two filters (the `term` and the `range`), so you need to use a compound `bool` filter to combine them together.  Otherwise, your syntax is correct.

Also, you forgot the 'title' field in the `match` query

Note:  I'm not sure how laravel works with respect to ES integration, but you'll probably need to put that whole thing inside a `query` block too.

Comment: Thanks @Zach I`ve also update the second query if you have the time to take a look. It works perfect I just want to make sure that I write it after "best practise"

Comment: Well mine "filtered" is wrapping the whole query. It still works fine but now sure if its the best way

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#_multiple_filters

Comment: Your updated query looks good to me!  That setup -- a filtered + query / filter section -- is definitely the ideal, best-practice way to do things.

Comment: Alright then, cheers @Zach ! I had to ask since I seen alot of people either putting the quey -> match - text inside the "filtered" and some outside the filtered. Like mine and yours :)

Comment: Np. If you only have queries to run (e.g. no filtering), it's totally fine to just use `query -> match`.  But as soon as you introduce a filter, you almost always want `query -> filtered -> filter/query`. 90% of my ES queries follow the `query -> filtered -> filter/query` pattern.

Comment: Filtered is deprecated since ES 2.0, just for future references